# Serious performance issue in nodejs when deal with many object with different keys

Tags: node.js, v8

According to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/), v8 engine will generate hidden class for each different type of object. Unfortunately, user need to be very careful designing data structure or they may get serious performance issue.

Please see the following code, this code runs very slow since v8 create hidden class for each 'obj' since they have different keys:

```
// run in nodejs v0.12
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++){
   var obj = {};
   obj[Math.random()] = true;
}
//too slow 35.8s!
```

However, when I add a trick in this code, the performance is 300 times faster

```
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++){
   var obj = {k : 1};
   delete obj.k; // trick v8 not to use hidden class
   obj[Math.random()] = true;
}
// 0.19s!
```

So the question is, is there a better way (official way) to avoid this kind of performance issue? I need to use Nodejs to handle tremendous data, hitting this performance issue is almost inevitable.

Comment: It would likely be more useful to see some real world code.  You're creating 100,000 separate objects each with one key and then using none of them so they all get garbage collected.  I'd probably work on a data storage/lookup mechanism that didn't require 100,000 separate objects long before I'd worry about hidden class performance differences.

Comment: I use node to process arbitrary data provided by users, some of the data is hashes like  {id1 : true, id2 : true},  so its easy to get too many objects with different ids